# Can SAML tokens be used to exchange symmetric keys?

Tags: security, authentication, kerberos, saml, sts-securitytokenservice

I would like the client connect to an STS to obtain a SAML token and use it to authenticate it self to a service, but I want the token to contain more information than the standard SAML token, I would also like to avoid using transport level security.
In a sense it will be very similar to a kerberos ticket having the session key

is this possible?

Comment: I think SAML 2.0 supports [tag:xml-encryption]. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423501/can-you-do-symmetric-encryption-on-saml-attributes-in-saml-2-0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, definetely possible. I've seen SAML [holder-of-key with symmetric](http://www.google.com/search?q=holder+of+key+saml+symmetric) encryption being applied in one place.